# Passing JSON parameter to function in GOLANG

Tags: json, go

I want to pass a JSON object to a function in GOLANG ,so how would I define my parameters,would it be fine if I can define my params as string .below is a sample

```
    func getDetailedNameSpace(authentication string,id string) string{
 var jsonStr = []byte(string);
tr := &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
    }

    client := &http.Client{Transport: tr}

    req, _ := http.NewRequest("PUT", "https://"+authentication.endPoint+"/object/namespaces/"+id, bytes.NewBuffer(jsonStr))
    req.Header.Add("X-Sds-Auth-Token",authentication.authtoken)
    req.Header.Add("Accept","application/json")
    res,err:=client.Do(req)

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)

    if err!=nil{
    fmt.Printf("%s",err)

    }
    return string(body);


}
```

Also i have to validate the params ,as in python we can have like below

```
 def getDetailedNameSpace(authentication,id=None):
       assert authentication!=None,"Authentication Required"
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're trying to put the JSON as the body of your `PUT` request. In this case you'll just want to use assignment. The request object has a field of type `io.ReadCloser` for it.

```
  req.Header.Add("Accept","application/json")
  req.Body = bytes.NewBufferString(MyJsonAsAString)
  res,err:=client.Do(req)
```

There are some other methods like `http.Post` which take the body as an argument but in this case, the `Do` method takes a `Request` object as an argument and that has a property for the `Body`.

Comment: In the parameters for the function should i take the  eg: authentication in this case should be a json obejct,so should i take it as a string

Comment: @asj177 if you have your json stored in a string then you would pass into `NewBufferString` I used the term `MyJsonAsString` to represent this json you want to use as the request body. If you have an object, then you would use `json.Marshal(&MyObject)` to create a string representation of it.

Comment: Ok I have a json such as lets say 
{"namespaceadmins":"asj",
  "datalist":["avx","bdx","xnf"],
   "attributes":{
"name":"aj",
"listedvalues":["12","14","13"],
},
"id":12,
"groups":["ab","kl"]
}

now how can i create this json as I want to send this data in a post request

Comment: @asj177 well if that is exactly what you want you could use a string literal like; `req.Body = bytes.NewBufferString({"namespaceadmins":"asj", "datalist":["avx","bdx","xnf"], "attributes":{ "name":"aj", "listedvalues":["12","14","13"], }, "id":12, "groups":["ab","kl"] })` but I don't really understand how your json data is being stored/read ect in your program. put the string in ` for quotes, I can't type it in the comment because it's what designates a code snippet.